# BAPI_SALESORDER_CHANGE throws type exception

Tags: abap, bapi, function-module

I'm having trouble using the FM `BAPI_SALESORDER_CHANGE`.

As soon as I execute my report, an exception is thrown by the FM. Following is the dump of the exception.

```
An exception occurred that is explained in detail below.
The exception, which is assigned to class 'CX_SY_DYN_CALL_ILLEGAL_TYPE', was
 not caught and
therefore caused a runtime error.
The reason for the exception is:
The call to the function module "BAPI_SALESORDER_CHANGE" is incorrect:

In the function module interface, you can specify only
fields of a specific type and length under "ORDER_HEADER_IN".
Although the currently specified field
"LS_ORDER_HEADER_IN" is the correct type, its length is incorrect.
```

Now, I got that `LS_ORDER_HEADER_IN`'s length is incorrect. But what I don't understand is why it is incorrect.

Following is my report's code:

```
REPORT ztesting.

DATA:
      lv_sales_document   TYPE bapivbeln-vbeln,

      ls_order_header_in  TYPE bapisdhd1,
      lt_order_header_in  TYPE TABLE OF bapisdhd1,

      ls_order_header_inx TYPE bapisdhd1x,
      lt_order_header_inx TYPE TABLE OF bapisdh1x,

      lt_return           TYPE TABLE OF bapiret2,

      ls_order_item_in    TYPE bapisditm,
      lt_order_item_in    TYPE bapisditm OCCURS 0 WITH HEADER LINE,

      ls_order_item_inx   TYPE bapisditmx,
      lt_order_item_inx   TYPE bapisditmx OCCURS 0 WITH HEADER LINE,

      ls_schedule_lines   TYPE bapischdl,
      lt_schedule_lines   TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapischdl WITH HEADER LINE,

      ls_schedule_linesx  TYPE bapischdlx,
      lt_schedule_linesx  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF bapischdlx WITH HEADER LINE,

      ls_return           TYPE bapiret2.

lv_sales_document               = '5999999'.

ls_order_header_inx-updateflag  = 'U'.

ls_order_item_in-itm_number     = '10'.
ls_order_item_inx-itm_number    = 'X'.

ls_order_item_in-material       = '16'.
ls_order_item_inx-material      = 'X'.

ls_order_item_inx-updateflag    = 'U'.

ls_schedule_lines-itm_number    = '10'.
ls_schedule_linesx-itm_number   = 'X'.

ls_schedule_lines-req_qty       = '1000'.
ls_schedule_linesx-req_qty       = 'X'.


ls_schedule_linesx-req_qty    = 'X'.

APPEND:
  ls_order_header_inx TO lt_order_header_inx,
  ls_order_header_in TO lt_order_header_in,
  ls_order_item_in TO lt_order_item_in,
  ls_order_item_inx TO lt_order_item_inx,
  ls_schedule_lines TO lt_schedule_lines,
  ls_schedule_linesx TO lt_schedule_linesx.

CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_SALESORDER_CHANGE'
  EXPORTING
    salesdocument    = lv_sales_document
    order_header_in  = ls_order_header_in
    order_header_inx = ls_order_header_inx
  TABLES
    return           = lt_return
    order_item_in    = lt_order_item_in
    order_item_inx   = lt_order_item_inx
    schedule_lines   = lt_schedule_lines
    schedule_linesx  = lt_schedule_linesx.

DATA: lt_return2 TYPE TABLE OF bapiret2.
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT'
  EXPORTING
    wait = 'X'.

LOOP AT lt_return INTO ls_return.
  WRITE: / sy-subrc, ls_return-type, ls_return-number, ls_return-id, ls_return-message.
ENDLOOP.
```

Also, can you spot any other mistakes I've made? It's the first time I'm using this function.
Note: I copied the code from the SAP Forum. I just modified values and variable names.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Diego.

Comment: It's just a typo in your code. Don't type the names manually, especially when the compiler tells you the type is incorrect, copy and paste them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your types for header are wrong, you need:

```
  ls_order_header_in TYPE bapisdh1
```

instead of bapisdh**d**1, and

```
  ls_order_header_inx TYPE bapisdh1x
```

instead of bapisdh**d**1x. The table types must also match this.

They looks almost similar, but they are not the same, the ones you used are structures for  generic SD document, not SO.